# Ordering strings by length without using an array in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to take a set of strings given at the command line and use the comparable interface to order them at first by length and, in the case of a tie, lexiographical order.

The first thing I'm having trouble with is grouping the words given at the command line without using an array. Then I need a pointer on how to order them by length...

the way I have my program setup is:
 1. class 'stringy' with a main method
 2. Class 'LengthSortableString' which implements comparable and has a constructor that takes a string argument. Also has a getContents method which returns a string and has no arguments, as well as the compareTo method.

thanks for any help

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Are you allowed to use built-in collections (such as `List`)?

Comment: Sounds homeworky... Either way, check out a book called Effective Java by Josh Bloch. Item 25 will get you started

Comment: The strings that you pass in via the command line are passed in as an array (String[] args), so theyre already in an array

Answer (score 1):

Without writing code...

Use a `Set<String>` to hold the words - just `add()` them to it.

When it comes time to order them, create a `List<String>` and `addAll()` the set.

Use `Colllections.sort()` with a custom `Comparator<String>`, whose `compare()` method makes the comparison you describe; if the two Strings have the same length, return the comparison between the two Strings, otherwise return the comparison of the lengths.

If the input won't ever contain duplicates, you can skip the Set and use a List from the start.